# Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'groupped'

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, ranking

I've the following code:

```
Input_File = load '/user/cloudera/teste' USING PigStorage (' ')
      as (ID:Int, 
          Descrip:Chararray,
          Date:Datetime);

groupped = group Input_File by (ID, Date);

ranked = foreach groupped {
        ranked = rank groupped by ID desc DENSE;
        generate flatten(ranked);
        }

STORE ranked into '/user/cloudera/teste1123';
```

I'm trying to create rank column on this dataset:

```
id  des date
1   A   01-01-2016
2   A   02-01-2016
2   C   03-01-2016
2   D   03-01-2016
3   A   01-01-2016
```

The main goal is to get this:

```
rank    id  desc    date
1       1   A   01-01-2016
2       2   A   02-01-2016
3       2   C   03-01-2016
3       2   D   03-01-2016
4       3   A   01-01-2016
```

But when I'm running my code I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR 1200: <line 5, column 14>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'groupped'

Failed to parse: <line 5, column 14>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'groupped'
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:241)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:179)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.validateQuery(PigServer.java:1660)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1633)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:587)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:1090)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:501)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:547)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

What I am doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: If the rank column has the same value as the id column then you can just create a new id column and name it as rank.

Comment: Are you sure `groupped` can be referenced inside of the `foreach groupped` block?

Comment: inquisitive_mind sorry, I copy the wrong data to the post...

Comment: cricket_007 I think yes, but I don't have a big experience on PIG Latin...

Comment: It is already updated... I just trying to get Rank based on ID and Date

Comment: Yeah, me neither, which is why I asked. Also, to notify someone please put an @ like @<username>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where the syntax error is, however here is the solution you are looking for.

Note: You will have to load date as chararray

```
Input_File = load '/user/cloudera/teste' USING PigStorage(' ') as (ID:int, Descrip:chararray,Date:chararray);
ranked = rank Input_File by ID ASC,Date DENSE;
dump ranked;
```

Output

[image]